# SQL Server parallels to Oracle DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle, scripting, ddl

I'm looking for command line or scripted solutions to pull the DDL out of SQL Server 2005+ for all database objects: tables, stored procs, views, indices/indexes, constraints, etc. GUI tools are not of interest.

Preference is for built-in tools, since that would be the most comparable to Oracle's DBMS_METADATA stuff. Also, preference for a solution that is as simple as Oracle's for getting the DDL out - eg, a one liner:

```
    SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE') FROM DUAL
```

Note: Getting things out for procedures in SQL Server 2005 seems easy, but I can't find any references to something similar for other objects (like tables).

```
    SELECT definition 
    FROM Sys.sql_modules 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyProc')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems the oracle syntax is really 'select ... from dual'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support in the Transact-SQL language. The client libraries (SMO) can do it using a [Scripter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx) object, see example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153.aspx. You can use SMO from PowerShell as a scripted solution.

The SQL Management Studio also has an option (right click on a database, go to Tasks, select Generate Scripts), it uses an SMO Scripter under the covers.

Comment: I had a suspicion that there might not have been anything similar to get the DDL out in a one liner. I'll investigate the SMO stuff - thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [SMOscript](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/10/17/scripting-all-ms-sql-databases-using-smoscript/), a command-line tool which uses SMO to generate DDL files of all database objects.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give SMOscript a look!