# In Oracle, how do I create the "CREATE TABLE..." syntax for an existing table?

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL Server has a way to let you "export" an existing table's schema, in the form of its necessary SQL "Create Table" commands.

How do you do this in Oracle?  Is there a nice automated way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Server parallels to Oracle DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511956/sql-server-parallels-to-oracle-dbmsmetadata-getddl)

Gives a good example.

Answer (score 3):

Using a tool like SQL Developer or Toad is probably simplest. But the information is all available in the data dictionary. In particular, check the documentation for DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl. Something like

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl ('TABLE',myschema,mytab) from dual;
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SQLDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) for this.
It is freely available and you can just right click on the table and can export the DDL query,export data in various format,etc.

Below is the link to sample Export HOW-To
http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/howtos/export_intro.htm